# Check if more than one call with a given timestamp falls within a 3-minute period of a day

Tags: excel, parsing, time

**Timestamp - Number table**

[image: Timestamp- number table]

So the given is an Excel table of phone calls with one column for call start timestamps in the extended format (MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS) and the other one for the corresponding "from" phone number. The table itself is over 1 mln entries long that cover the span of several days, and my goal is to make sure only 1 call from a unique number per a 3-minute chunk of the day stays in the table. So for instance if the 1st call  from the number 1234567890 is made on 19:30 and the 2nd one from the SAME number - on 19:32, the second one (and all consequtive ones from the same number until 19:33) should be deleted (or greyed out for that matter). I am not quite experienced with programming and I can't figure out how to make Excel check if an entry falls into a given 3-minute period, let alone how to make it mark/delete entries if there already is one with the same number made in the same 3-minute period already.

What I tried was that I divided the entire day into 3-minute periods (00:00-00:03, 00:03-00:06, 00:06-00:09, etc) and managed to set up a check if a given timestamp falls into a 3-minute period using a TIMEVALUE function first to convert timestamps to values and then using a simple `"=IF(AND(F12>0.0, F12<0.002083333333), "yes", "no")` for 00:00-00:03 timestamp for example. However, it only works with a single period, and I can't figure out how to check if two timestamps with the same number fall into ANY single time period, not just the given one.

What I've theoretically figured out so far is that I need to set up a variable that would change whenever a an entry with a certain number in a certain period of time is detected in the table, and then nullified again when this period of time ends and another begins (since the table is sorted by ascending timestamps). So when another call from the same number pops up, it would check whether the variable is "triggered" and if yes, all further entries for the same number over the same 3-minute period are deleted.

Please help me wrap my head around it.

**Original data**

| Timestamp | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567891 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567893 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567903 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:32 | 1234567892 |
| 12/6/2004 19:34 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:35 | 1234567895 |

**Expected result**

| Timestamp | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567891 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567893 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:31 | 1234567903 |
| 12/6/2004 19:32 | 1234567892 |
| 12/6/2004 19:34 | 1234567890 |
| 12/6/2004 19:35 | 1234567895 |

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is much easier to help you if you (1) provide some sample data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and (2) show us your expected output. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you want to delete the extra entries then you will need vba - have a look on here for code deleting rows.

Comment: Your attached table is not sorted by timestamp. What is the proper state?

Comment: Apologies, this should be the proper state
12/6/2004 19:30 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567891
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567893
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567903
12/6/2004 19:31 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:32 1234567892
12/6/2004 19:34 1234567890
12/6/2004 19:35 1234567895

so, in the above table calls from 1234567890 were made several times during the period 00:00-00:03. I'm trying to create a setup that would only leave the 1st instance.

Comment: Pls. in the future if possible use Markdown for data tables (as i) to make easier to reproduce a process.

Comment: Black cat, thank you for your help with formatting. I will certainly try to use the appropriate formatting going forward, sorry for the mess. 

Foxfire And Burns And Burns, right, I want to get unique phone calls for every 3-minute period. So, if another call from the same number happened in another 3-minute period, it should not be deleted as long as it is the first over the given 3-minute period.

Comment: @RexCaesar please provide the expected result. You are collecting the start time, but not the end time, how it is supposed to calculate the call duration? For example for the number: `1234567890` you have several entries starting at the same time for the same day:`19:31`. How to connect the start and the end of the call to calculate the duration for the same number? Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal Hi David, thank you for your response. I only have call start timestamps and I don't need to consider call duration in the calculations, I only need to make sure no more than 1 call initiated from the given number per each 3-minute period of the day is left.

Comment: Added the expected results. As you can see, only 1 call made at 19:31 from the number 1234567890 is left. At the same time, there is also a call from this number made at 19:34 that is legitimately there since it was made at a different 3-minute piece of the day.